# Getting Uploadify Working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, uploadify

This seemed like it should be easy, but I have had trouble getting it to work. I don't know why it doesn't.  It is just showing the normal file input.

Is there any code / examples to get this working.  I am getting frustrated...

Thank you all.

Comment: what is uploadify? what are the problems you're having? do you have example code of your own that you've tried?

Comment: Uploadify is great.  @JoelMartinez: http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Uploadify is an upload control...uploadify.com.  Looks neat.  The JQuery thing made the button show up but it still doesn't work.  I am gonna watch this video and see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a video tutorial on how to get started using C# and Webforms, should help you.

http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx

Can you post your code though so that I might be able to show you what you are doing wrong?

Here is the sample code I have for asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       // <![CDATA[
       var id = "55";
       var theString = "asdf";
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#fileInput').uploadify({
       'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
       'script': 'Upload.ashx',
       'scriptData': { 'id': id, 'foo': theString},
       'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
       'auto': true,
       'multi': true,
       'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
       'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
       'queueSizeLimit': 90,
       'sizeLimit': 4000000,
       'buttonText': 'Choose Images',
       'folder': '/uploads',
       'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

       }
     });
   });
   // ]]></script>

   <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Then you want to make a Handler (.ashx):

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file= context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

            int id = (Int32.Parse(context.Request["id"]));
            string foo = context.Request["foo"];
            file.SaveAs("C:\\" + id.ToString() + foo + file.FileName);

            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Post your code and I will take a look at it.  Sounds like you are pointing to a resource that doesn't exist.  Maybe your 'uploader' property is not pointed to the proper resource or your jquery link is broken (or not there).

Comment: Just a heads up that a lot of the parameters described in this answer have changed. I suggest always checking the latest documentation.