# Can Uploadify send e-mail on complete?

Tags: .net, jquery-plugins, uploadify

Uploadify is a jQuery/Flash plugin for uploading multiple files. It's working great, except I can't figure out how trigger e-mail when **all** files are complete. If I try to add something like `<% SendEmail(); %>` to the onAllComplete parameter, it just sends the e-mail when the page loads.

Is there a way to do this within the handler recommended [here](http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx) or from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501037/getting-uploadify-working-in-c)? Or is there some way to trigger a post in the onAllComplete parameter?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var FirstName = $('[id$=HiddenField4]').val();
    var MiddleName = $('[id$=HiddenField5]').val();
    var ClientName = $('[id$=HiddenField6]').val();
    var queueSize = $('#fileInput').uploadifySettings('queueSize');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'scriptData': { 'first': FirstName, 'middle': MiddleName, 'client': ClientName, 'queueSize': queueSize },
            'cancelImg': 'scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'auto': true,
            'multi': true,
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg;*.pdf',
            'queueSizeLimit': 90,
            'sizeLimit': 10000000,
            'buttonText': 'Upload Documents',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                 alert(response);
            },
            'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                 <% SendEmail(); %>
            },
            'buttonImg': 'images/upload.png'
         });
      });
      // ]]></script>
```

I've also tried queueSize declaring it as

```
var queueSize = $(".uploadifyQueueItem").size();
```

queueSize always posts as 0 when I debug my handler.

Comment: Can you include a code sample of what you're doing?  The explanation you've given (with angle brackets) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the instruction to send the E-Mail into the script that **receives** the uploaded file (`Upload.ashx` in your case.)

That file will be called when the upload has been finalized.

An alternative would be making an Ajax call in the `onComplete` callback, calling another ashx script that sends out the E-Mails. Anyway, there is no JavaScript way of sending out the E-Mail, you will have to do that on the server side.

Comment: The handler is executed once for every file. I need to send e-mail when all files (1 or more) are complete.

Comment: @David I see. Then check out the last paragraph I just added.

Comment: I understand there is no way to send e-mail client side, but I didn't know I could force an AJAX post from javascript. Should I look at jQuery.ajax() ?

Comment: @David yup, if you're running jQuery already then that is the nicest way. (See BalusC's answer for an example.)

Comment: awesome! thanks! Is it possible to post to .ashx? I did a .ajax() post to email.aspx and the page_load just sends the e-mail and dies.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear. I was informing you what I coded up. I should've said "Page_Load completes e-mail successfully and has given me tons of new ideas for jQuery ajax postbacks" :) I'm only familiar with .NET handler classes since I found this plugin, so I guess I'll have to read up no them

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve this at the server side. But Uploadify is an entirely client side script (JS+Flash). You need to write/invoke the mailing code in the server side which get invoked by an ajaxical call which you fire in `onAllComplete`. You can use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or consorts for this.

E.g.

```
        'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
             $.post('somescript.aspx', paramsWhichSignalsServerToSendMail);
        },
```

Comment: The handler is executed once for every file. I need to send e-mail when all files (1 or more) are complete.

Comment: you get the upvote for the code since I think it came in after Pekka's suggestion for the postback.

Comment: Actually, after your comment and maybe also because pekka mentioned `onComplete` instead of `onAllComplete`.