# Notify user control with files are uploaded - Uploadify

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I have a user control in which I have file upload control and `uploadify` script. I have a handler that is needed to upload files. In short I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501037/getting-uploadify-working-in-c-sharp) to use `uploadify` with asp.net. It is working fine. But I want to do some more task in code behind of that user control when all files are uploaded. How my user control will know that all files are done? Can't use jquery ajax because I have user control not aspx page, hence `WebMethod` will not be handle by it. Any other way?

Comment: can you share some code? You could just return a string for each upload you do with a success or fail message.

Comment: My code is noting more than mentioned link has

Comment: change the ProcessRequest method from void to string for example and set that string similar to that context.response and return it.